# Bootstrap fixed navbar : padding-top and body 100%

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For a client, I have to do fullscreen website, responsive design. I am using Bootstrap with a fixed navbar, so in order to place my content, I added a 60px padding-top to the body.

Here is my problem : the scrollbar shows systematically, because my body have a height of 100% and a 60px padding-top. I can use 'overflow: hidden;', but then if I need to scroll a page I can't anymore.

Do you have a solution ?

Thanks!

EDIT : Here is the idea : http://jsfiddle.net/StFca/
In this case, I would like the scrollbar to be hidden, 'cause there's no need of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding padding to the body, you can add a `margin-top: 60px` property to a new class or id that you can add to your main container of your content, so it would look something like this:

```
#main-container {
    margin-top: 60px;
}
```

This way you can accommodate your navbar by pushing the container itself away from it instead of the body of the document and the scrollbars will disappear.

Comment: Yep, but this is the same problem, systematic overflow =/

Comment: @JérémyDutheil Here is a demo i made with the same approach i posted above, http://jsfiddle.net/CDwKV/show/, the scrollbars are not appearing. Maybe some content is overflowing past the viewport in your case?

Comment: Here is my case : http://www.jeremy-dutheil.fr/barconniere/
You can see that I get an overflow even if the content is not too big =/

Comment: @JérémyDutheil Remove the `height:100%` declaration from your `html` tag and it should work. Also, you have multiple containers containing your content and that is not proper bootstrap setup so you can eliminate that second `<div class="container-fluid"> ... </div>` container after your main `<section>`

Comment: There is another case I would like to figure out : http://www.jeremy-dutheil.fr/barconniere/pages/enterprise
In this page, I would like the scrollbar to be on the text container, and not in the body ; is it possible ?

Comment: I still see the `html { height:100%; }` declaration on that page, which is causing the two scrollbars. Just eliminate that declaration and that container will use the pages scrollbar.

Comment: Hum, are you sure your cache is ok ? 'cause I don't have the declaration anymore, and only one scrollbar for the body so

Comment: @JérémyDutheil dang it, it was my cache, just cleared it and looks like you say. That problem requires a bit more attention than i can give right now (got work to do), i suggest you post it as a new question to get more attention to it and I'll see if i can get back to it during the day.